# $\mathbb{E}[\sigma(r)^2]$ with $r \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Tags: logistic, normal-distribution, variance, random-variable, integral

Start with a random variable $r \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Now consider the random variable $\sigma(r)$ formed by passing it through a standard logistic function $\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$. I would like to know the mean and variance of $\sigma(r)$.

The mean value is 0.5 by symmetry, but the variance is trickier. By definition
$$\mathrm{Var}[\sigma(r)] = \mathbb{E}[\sigma(r)^2] - \mathbb{E}[\sigma(r)]^2$$
and $\mathbb{E}[\sigma(r)]^2 = 0.25$.

Is there a way to calculate $\mathbb{E}[\sigma(r)^2]$ analytically?

Comment: With is the computation of the mean so obvious?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it follows from the symmetry of $r$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: I see. The key point is that $\sigma(x)+\sigma(-x)=1$, but I do not know whether a similar relation holds for $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Yes, $\sigma^2$ is not symmetric so there I doubt there's any similar identity

Comment: According to the wiki page for the logit-normal (the distribution you're describing), there are no analytical formula for the moments https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution. However, you could easily get a monte carlo approximation with a few lines of R.

Comment: Probably no analytical expression for $E[\sigma^2(r)]$. But for a "semi-analytical" solution, you may try Laplace approximation,

Comment: Interesting - I'm looking into this to justify an approximation I'm making in _another_ Laplace approximation.